# Does SASS render the css to a new css file , to an allready existing file or does it simply generate css when the page loads?

Tags: sass

Does SASS render to an actual css file of my choosing or a newly generated style sheet?

in the case of an app with many style sheets , the most sensible thing is replace some css at a time and render to a style sheet that loads last -that would override all other style sheets until the updating is done and I would remove css.

Comment: I read the docs I may have missed something but It didn't spell that out right away. I read the 'install' the 'Learn Sass' and the docs. since I have no ruby experience and I don't use the command line -I came here here to ask my simple and dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical Sass workflow is to compile to a main style.css file from a style.scss file where you specify which files it should compile. You can set it to compile to a different file. If you're using the command line you can tell it what to watch and where to output a la

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

```
sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets
```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Most GUIs that handle Sass have simple settings that allow you to do the same for individual files.

Answer (score 1):

It renders into an actual `CSS` file. All of the `SASS` is eventually compiled into vanilla `CSS`

Comment: can I designate the file it renders to?

Comment: Yep. It depends on how it compiles based on the framework you're using, but a common approach is to have a `styles.scss` file that contains an `@import` of all the `sass` files that you want in your one file. Then all you have to do is compile `styles.scss` into `styles.css`